# Chrome copies text despite using "-webkit-user-select: none"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I want to create an element within a table which is not copyable (because of better readability).

In Firefox it is working correctly. If you select everything and copy it, the specific text element is not beeing copied.

Sadly in Chrome this doesn't work. Indeed the browser does not select the text, but copies it.

```
<td unselectable="on" id="unselectable">Test2</td>

#unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pXAeB/

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/pXAeB/1/)

Add the below to your table element:

```
unselectable='on'
onselectstart='return false;' 
onmousedown='return false;'
```

To your table element. Note that for Chrome, most of the time just the inclusion of `onselectstart='return false;'` should suffice.

Comment: Alright, this seems to work for the whole table. But I only want the specific part of the table to be unselectable, not everything. Do you think, there might be a solution for this special case?

Comment: Of course, just add that line to the specific parts of the table you dont want to be selectable..

Comment: I set it on my table headings `<table><tr><th onselectstart='return false;'>Label1</th><td>Value1</td></tr><tr><th onselectstart='return false;'>Label2</th><td>Value2</td></tr></table>`, when selecting the row with Value1 for some reason it selects "Value1 Label2"

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Chrome (36). Selecting with CTRL+A still copies "Test2"

Comment: The fiddle does not work in Chrome. When using the mouse to select, `Test2` is not selected, but it is still copied. Here is the [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80159).