# make text not selectable on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Been trying to make some text within a

tag unelectable on an iPad, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone help please?

```css
#unselectable{
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none; 
  -moz-user-select: moz-none; 
  -ms-user-select: none; 
  -o-user-select: none; 
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="unselectable">Make this text unselectable, also on ipad.</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321081/chrome-copies-text-despite-using-webkit-user-select-none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the following code inside your css

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

So your css will be like this

```
#unselectable{
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
   user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              not supported by any browser */
 }
```

Hope it will work in safari. Let me know!